# JAVASCRIPT AJAX - Prevent redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajax({url:"URL",success:function(result){
```

I have a webpage that accesses a certain URL and then extract certain elements of the webpage. However, in order to access that URL you have to be redirected to what is similar to a log in page (requires form submission) and then you have access to that link.

I want to prevent the redirection upon loading the URL. Is that possible?

If not, am I able to manually do the form submission using JAVASCRIPT? Via AJAX or any other resource.

EDIT: By manually saving the .html to my directory and accessing the page from my root folder, it works fluently.

Thank you!

Comment: That's not possible. Where the request is redirected to is entirely determined by the receiving server. You haven't given us enough information to help with your latter request.

Comment: Is the webpage on a server you don't control?

Comment: Yes it's on a server I don't control.

Comment: Looks like you are accessing  an API, (e.g. Facebook)  please make sure if you need to implement oAuth REST API call. the reason you are redirected is the redirectionURL requirement of the API to return back to your site after your app or your user was authenthicated.

Comment: @agentpx It has to do with APIs but no, the URL I am requesting is not related to the API. I'm unsure if I may post the link I am trying to access to so you have an idea what I mean. Tell me if I'm allowed to and I'll post it.

Comment: @tempt yes it is allowed

Comment: www.addmesnaps.com/snapchat_online.php

Clicking the link should redirect you to the index page of the website.

Comment: Not possible it is a normal website not an API

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to stop the form submission and add your AJAX call. Like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"URL",
        success:function(result){
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**More information here.**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)

Comment: This doesn't prevent the server side redireection

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked.

Comment: @gibsonman507 you stated the `return false` isn't accessible, when it is.

Comment: @gibsonman507 please don't play games of deleting a comment and wonder why people make comments about it

Comment: $("button").click(function(){
     $.ajax({url:"URL",success:function(result){

To be precise, my code is as above ^^, I click on a button and it calls ajax with the URL I have in, however when the URL is called it automatically redirects to a different webpage that serves a different purpose than what I want. Does return false do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you need to do is log the user into the external website programmatically beforehand. This is possible if the other site supports [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) or something similar, but the specifics will depend on their API and what exactly you're trying to do. I can't tell you more than that without more information.

This assumes you're trying to include the other web page in an iFrame, or link directly to a page there, or something like that. If, on the other hand, you're trying to *log in to the foreign website as the user,* pull out some content, and mix it in with your own, then I suggest you change your approach. You'll probably run afoul of all kinds of anti-XSS security policies, either on the foreign website or in the browser depending on what you try to do. Or you'll have to ask your users to give you their password on another site, and they'll have to really trust you for that.

Generally speaking, if you want to interact with another website, the user's client should connect, log in, and receive content directly from the other server without you acting as an intermediary. I think perhaps you're asking the wrong question: Instead of "how can I do this without the user logging in," ask "how can I let the user connect and log in to another website without having to leave my page?"

Comment: The website does not require me to log in. All it asks me to do is write a valid username (could be anything) and press "Add Me" and I will have access to the URL. I don't know how to approach that.

Comment: Do they have an API? You said "it is a normal website not an API," but that doesn't mean they don't have an API *also.*

Comment: I'm unsure. www.addmesnaps.com/snapchat_online.php